# How do I incorporate FFMpeg into Laragon Local Server?

Tags: ffmpeg, laragon

I need to use FFMpeg on my project to automatically generate thumbnails from videos uploaded to my site.  I understand you need FFMpeg to do this.  I can't seem to find any information on how to install FFMpeg into the Laragon Local Server. I found older tutorials on how to install FFMpeg into Xampp for example, but they are now out of date as the latest FFMpeg uses different file structures etc. Anyone know how to install FFMpeg to Laragon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kevin K:
It is very simple to use FFMpeg with Laragon. Here's how:

1. Download the binaries:
   https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2021-06-01-13-18/ffmpeg-n4.4-19-g8d172d9409-win64-gpl-4.4.zip
2. Unzip and move the 3 files in `bin` to `C:\laragon\bin`

- ffmpeg.exe
- ffplay.exe
- ffprobe.exe

3. Open Laragon's Terminal  **Menu > Laragon > Terminal** and check:

```
ffmpeg -v
```

You should use FFMpeg in your PHP code with library like:
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Ref: https://forum.laragon.org/topic/2448/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-edit-video-with-laragon